# Wrong Barcode when printing in python using zebra.0.05

Tags: python

I have written a scipt that is supposed to print a barcode label using a zebra lp2824 printer. I am using the zebra.0.0.5 library for this. The script is getting data using sys .My problem is that the barcode being printed has the wrong last digit every time I print.so how can I solve this? This is my code:

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python
 import sys
 from zebra import zebra
 hospital = str(sys.argv[1]).zfill(5)
 identifier = str(sys.argv[2]).zfill(8)
 barcode = hospital + identifier

if __name__ == '__main__': 
      z= zebra('Zebra_LP2824')
      z.setqueue('Zebra_LP2824')
      z.setup(direct_thermal=True, label_height=(50,10),              label_width=80)
      z.store_graphic('logo','logo.pcx')
      label = """
N
q406
Q203,026
ZT
B50,10,0,E30,3,7,150,B,"{0}"
P1
""".format(str(barcode))
        z.output(label)
```

Comment: Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, hard to provide guidance without knowing what you do, have tried, results, errors, logs, ...

Comment: Sorry about that, first time poster here, added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be generating a EAN13 barcode, a symbology which has a mandatory check digit at the end.  The software is helpfully replacing your arbitrary final digit with the proper check digit (calculated from the 12 other digits); a normal barcode reader would refuse to recognize your label otherwise.

Basically, EAN13 was a poor choice here - it has too rigid of a format, and too much preassigned meaning, to be suitable for encoding arbitrary data.  Consider Code128 instead - it can encode data of arbitrary length, and is especially compact with numeric data (yet can encode arbitrary ASCII text if you need it).

Comment: That seems like a fair guess, but how do you know that EAN 13 is being generated? I don't see any symbology being selected in the shown code.

Comment: @MarkRansom It's the `E30` parameter to the `B` (barcode) command.